# PHP Symfony parameter to expected to be a reference, value given in bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: php, symfony, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am passing one optional parameter to route.

Till yesterday this was working, 
all of sudden getting this error

[image]

Controller code

```
/**
     * @Route("/usersFbVideo",name="_create_fb_social_gration")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function usersFbVideoAction(Request $request, $call_from=null,&$user_visiting_card_path=null)
    {  
     ......
    }
```

function submit code from .html.twig file

```
<form id="create_my_video" method="post" action="{{ path('_create_fb_social_gration')}}">                   </form> 
        <div class="popupBg"></div>
        <div class="popupBox small">
          <div class="popup-content">
             Please wait, we are processing your request
          </div>
       </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit();
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That error means, *you are passing "value/constant" instead of "variable"* to `usersFbVideoAction()`

Comment: last 2 params are optional right, when I am submitting, nothing is passed to it..
till yesterday it was working.. :(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Default value `NULL` should work for reference parameters. However did you changed `strict mode`? It will affect strict mode standards.

Comment: refer second ans --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280385/php-by-reference-parameters-and-default-null

Comment: ok correct, now in symfony what I need to find is how to send null variable to route from twig ..