# Pass default value instead of reference

Tags: php, function, function-signature

I have a function like this (using PHP 7.1):

```
function myfunction(&$first = null, $second = null)
{   // do something
}
```

What I want to achieve is to pass null as the first parameter and pass something as the second parameter:

```
myfunction(null, $something);
```

When I do that I get the "**Only variables can be passed by reference**" error.

But of course, null is the default of the first parameter, so the function was designed to handle null as the first parameter.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP by-reference parameters and default null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280385/php-by-reference-parameters-and-default-null)

Comment: You can call by changing parameter order like  myfunction($something);  dont pass second and change function to myfunction($second = null, &$first = null){ } //$first take the default value if not passed

Comment: @NigelRen: The other question is useless because you cannot find it when you search for "Only variables can be passed by reference"

Comment: Why is it useless because you can't use those words to search for it?  The purpose of a duplicate is that it's there because it answers the same problem as your having.

Comment: I searched both in Google and on Stackoverflow and was not able to find it - plus if you compare the answers, the other one is copy&pasted code with more than half unrelated to the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of sending `null`, you can send an undeclared variable, like ([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/jNgK7)):

```
<?php
function myfunction(&$first = null, $second = null)
{   // do something
}
myfunction($null, $something);
```

This will serve the purpose of executing the function and not breaking your code.

#### PHP 8+:

In PHP 8 we have [Named Parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params), so we don't even need to pass the `$first` param if we don't want to ([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/CXtIZ)):

```
<?php
function myfunction(&$first = null, $second = null)
{   // do something
}
myfunction(second: $something);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. A reference cannot be empty as first parameter if the function has more than 1 parameter.

Here are some possibilities:

```
function func($a = null, &$b = null) {}
function funcb(&$a, $b = null) {}
```

calling:

```
$a = null;
func($a, $b)
funcb($a)
```